# Summation in Matlab without for/while loop

Tags: matlab

How Do i solve this summation in MATLAB without using for/while loop?
Here C is a vector(1*N matrix), n=length(c) and x is scalar.
c(1)*x^1+c(2)*x^2+c()*x^3+....+c(n)*x^n.

Or can i Create a matrix with all element equal to x but with increasing power, like x, x^2,x^3....?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways:

- `result = polyval(fliplr([0 c]), x);`
- `result = sum(c.*x.^(1:numel(c)));`
- `result = sum(c.*cumprod(repmat(x, 1, numel(c))));`

As an example, for

```
c = [3 4 -5 2 3];
x = 9;
```

any of the above gives

```
result =
      186975
```

Check:

```
>> c(1)*x^1+c(2)*x^2+c(3)*x^3+c(4)*x^4+c(5)*x^5
ans =
      186975
```

Comment: Nice options :) It's just me that see here straight vector multiplication...?     `c*x.^(1:numel(c))'` . Actually it's your second option, in other writing...